# how to find number and calculate (change original number) within document

Tags: javascript, python, regex, replace, sequences

I have a text with numbers:

```
width: 32px;
height: 11px;
top: 102px;
left: 36px;

width: 32px;
height: 11px;
top: 102px;
left: 104px;

width: 32px;
height: 11px;
top: 102px;
left: 104px;
```

and I want to find each number in div/file/document and multiply it by 0,25 = to scale sizes down by 25%. And finally round that to whole number (optional). I want to take a short-cut with repetitive task, but get stuck ;)

I will accept any solution in javascript or python ..or anything fast. I have got so far: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvyWqb Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide your attempt so far? SO does not write code for free.

Comment: sure http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvyWqb

Comment: Please put a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **in your question**, along with a precise description of the problem with it (e.g. error traceback, inputs and expected and actual outputs).

Comment: I rolled back your last edit that added @wolffer-east's answer in your question. You are not a new user (although you never took the [Introductory Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)), and you should have known SO is a site for *questions and answers*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following function:

```
function return_quarter(str) {
  return str.replace(/([0-9]+)/g,function (number) {
    return Math.round(number * .25);
  });
}
```

`return_quarter('width: 32px; height: 11px; top: 102px; left: 36px;')` returns `"width: 8px; height: 3px; top: 26px; left: 9px;"`

Edit:

Looking at your code, you need to catch everything withing the brackets, not the classes themselves.  Nested replace it is!

```
function return_quarter(str) {
  return str.replace(/(\{[^}]*\})/g,function (innards) {
    console.log(innards)
    return innards.replace(/([0-9]+)/g,function (number) {
      return Math.round(number * .25);
    });
  });
}
```

Give that a shot when you have a chance

Comment: oop, forgot to drop the console log.  Take it out if you use this